# Should a JSON response from a REST API be url-encoded?

Tags: json, api, rest

I am developing a RESTful API which will operate through JSON messages, both received and sent.

The question is, when I return the result of an API call as `application/json`, should the response also be URL-encoded?

For example, is it more correct

```
{"status":"OK","id":"WjY3T2g2Z1JGV1dFcXRqcXh4TDBlNnd1bHlwMVVLVzBRWnU1TTBnWGwrUEFKTHd5RlZSSytRMmdMTnlBS1ViUg%3D%3D"}
```

or

```
{"status":"OK","id":"WjY3T2g2Z1JGV1dFcXRqcXh4TDBlNnd1bHlwMVVLVzBRWnU1TTBnWGwrUEFKTHd5RlZSSytRMmdMTnlBS1ViUg=="}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name suggests url encoding is for URL's so there's no need to apply it to your JSON, unless, the value is a URL.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, I'm glad to see I was on the right track!